# How mysql works with processes?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql  Ver 14.16 Distrib 5.2.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2, tables MyISAM
```

Situation: two select queries from two different clients to one database and tables (query with join).
Processor on server has 8 cores.
I want to know, isn't start two processes, one for each client, and one from 8 core execute every process?
It's possible? Is any MySQL/MariaDBoption for max_process or something else?
As i understand, one mysql process can work with 1 core of processor. I make google search for it, and find information about some plugin for InnoDB tables, which works with multicore processors, but i want understand how mysql works. 
What i need to reed about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (MySQL 5.5+) MySQL has no restriction on the number of threads, and your OS will be in charge of scheduling the threads (splitting them between processors, etc.).

Read about:

[**innodb_thread_concurrency**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency)

> A recommended value is 2 times the number of CPUs plus the number of
>   disks.

To read more in depth on this topic read [Changes Regarding Thread Concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-performance-thread_concurrency.html) and [How MySQL Uses Threads for Client Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-threads.html).